# Printing the raw contents of default CSS files with drupal_get_css

Tags: css, drupal, module, drupal-7

I have a custom Drupal 7 module that prints out the contents of a form, parses it and replaces all the form elements with equivalent divs, then prints out the HTML using `DOMDocument()`.

This is then run through [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to generate a PDF. I also have a little `preg_replace` that converts all occurrences of `textarea/input` to `.div-textarea/.div-input` in some inline CSS.

The issue, however, is that the default Drupal CSS files and the CSS files that are included in the custom theme are unable to be processed by this regex, because the `drupal_get_css()` function returns `<link>` tags and CSS's `@import` rule.

So the question is: do you know how I can get Drupal's theme output to print the actual raw contents of the CSS files in the HTML rather than these stylesheet links so that I can run the replacement function over it?

Or are there any better ways of copying CSS rules from one element/class to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this using a php funciton: [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Then your code looks something like:

```
$css = file_get_contents(drupal_get_path('theme', 'my_theme') . 'css/my_css.css');
```

Then you can print that css in any template or append to any string to get your output.

Edit:

To get a list of all css files run: `$css_list = drupal_add_css();`

Comment: Thanks for the answer; the only issue I have now though is that I don't want to necessarily manually add each CSS file as there are quite a few- do you know a way I can get an array of all the CSS files that will be loaded so I can loop through? Cheers! :)

Comment: Edited my asnwer above. Just run drupal_add_css with no parameters and it will return all css stylesheets in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the CSS loaded as a string (see @danielson317's answer for a good example of how to do this) add to the head using [`drupal_add_html_head()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7).

If you add the second `key` param, you can run your regex using [`hook_html_head_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_html_head_alter/7).